Mayer-Vietoris for Sheaf with support vs Usual Mayer-Vietoris
In Hartshorne Chapter III, Exercise 2.4, (for a topological space $X = Y_1\cup Y_2$) one is asked to prove the exactness of
$$
\ldots \to H^i_{Y_1\cap Y_2} (X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^i_{Y_1} (X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^i_{Y_1\cup Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \to \ldots,
$$
where $H^i_Y(X,\mathcal{F})$ denotes the cohomology with support contained in $Y$.
But on the other hand, the standard Mayer-Vietoris goes in the "other" direction
$$
\ldots \to H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) \to H^i(Y_1,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i(Y_2,\mathcal{F}) \to H^i(Y_1\cap Y_2,\mathcal{F}) \to \ldots
$$
How is this not a contradiction?

I think you have missed something. It is not the case that $X= Y_1\cup Y_2$: the only assumption is that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are closed subsets of $X$. The usual Mayer-Vietoris is for the situation when $X=U_1\cup U_2$ and $U_i$ are open subsets.
The fact that $Y_1,Y_2$ are closed while $U_1,U_2$ are open forces the behavior of the exact sequences. For $Y_1,Y_2$, you cannot in general produce a map $\Gamma_{Y_1\cup Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F})\to \Gamma_{Y_1}(X,\mathcal{F})\oplus \Gamma_{Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F})$ (how would you make sure you split up a section in to parts supported only on one of the $Y_i$?) but there is an obvious inclusion map from $\Gamma_{Y_1\cap Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F})\to \Gamma_{Y_1}(X,\mathcal{F})\oplus \Gamma_{Y_2}(X,\mathcal{F})$ which you can then continue with. For $U_1,U_2$, the opposite is true - the only general map you can get is $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})\to\Gamma(U_1,\mathcal{F})\oplus\Gamma(U_2,\mathcal{F})$, which you can then continue on with.
